# Invalid type conversion when building for x64 but x86 OK

Tags: types, casting, visual-studio-2017

Program builds and runs OK (almost***) for x86 but I get a type conversion error when building for 64bit.  MFC / ATL

Got a demo program from CodeProject that matches what I want to do.  It was for VC6 (old) but the conversion to VS2017 went ok.  ***If I run the debug version from the command prompt (win10x64) I get a McAfee Virus warning "Suspect"   I try running the debug version under VS2017 debug the virus warning states "REAL Protect-xxxx" instead of just "Suspect".  I am not sure if this has anything to do with my x64 compilation error but I thought it should be mentioned.

```
Error   C2440   'static_cast': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl CTestOScopeDlg::* )(UINT)' to 'void (__cdecl CWnd::* )(UINT_PTR)'
```

[image]

The above error message shows up as soon as x64 is selected.  Tried rebuild and batch build thinking the problem was the StdAfx.h include but still got error.

Comment: Please post a short example program that triggers the error: a [mcve].

Comment: I downloaded this stripchart demo program https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/241/Oscilloscope-StripChart-Control and VS2017 (with latest updates) converted it to new solution. I ran fine with "start without debugger" but McAfee wont let the debug version run.  Select "x64" to see the error show up  I program in C, VB,  and C# and retired 8 years ago and this is my first foray into MFC and I diont like it.

Comment: FORGOT!!:  I did change to Unicode char set and added L in front of every string that had an error message during compilation as I need to use Unicode char set